# How to fix the issue of Firefox cuts off part of a letter

Tags: css, firefox

And how do we make the following to show every letter when whatever is inputted in this email input box?

Currently, Firefox browser cuts off part of letter (meaning, the lower part of the letter is invisible upon typing) but Chrome and Safari is perfectly good, for instance, ‘g’ and ‘y’.

```
<input type="email" name="email" style="height: 30px; border: 2px solid #BDD3FF;">
```

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps **height: 1.2em** ?

Comment: It didn't, thanks tho, but I've fixed it by adding padding: 3.25px 8px;

Answer (score 1):

The problem is height is not enough to display the full letter in Firefox. So you can increase the hight. Something like that,

```
<input type="email" name="email" style="height: 35px; border: 2px solid #BDD3FF;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix it by adding the attribute of padding: 3.25px 8px;